# Using earpods from iphone5 with iphone 3g

Tags: ear-phones

I'm about to buy earpods, but since i have iphone 3g, and i didnt find any info on its compatibility, would like to know if they will work with old iphone? AFAIK every 3.5inch headphones will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they work as expected. I'm using them at the moment with an older phone.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Apple's Earpod product page](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MD827LL/A/apple-earpods-with-remote-and-mic), they aren't compatible with the iPhone 3G at first glance because they aren't listed in the compatible products section.

**However,** under "Compatibility Information" you should be set:

> The remote and mic are supported by all models of iPod, iPhone, and iPad (not all models support volume up/down functions). Audio is supported by all iPod models.

So, while not exactly under compatible products, they should work on your iPhone.